# In-App Purchase Sandbox completely broken on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, app-store, macos-catalina, in-app

I have a sandbox test user which I used to test In-App purchases. Everything was working until I upgraded to macOS Catalina (10.15.3).
If I try to refresh a receipt when it's not available with **SKReceiptRefreshRequest()** it fails with error: **Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"**.

Calling **exit(173)** shows error message: **{application name} is damaged and can't be opened. Delete {application name} and download it again from the App Store**.

In any case I can see a warning in Console.app: **Subsystem: com.apple.commerce Category: CommerceKit message: : Error fetching receipt for {application name} - Error Domain=com.apple.commerce.server Code=500317 "(null)"**.

There was no problem on Mojave so it was broken in Catalina. Did anyone found a solution?

Comment: Have you tried logging out of the App Store as mentioned in this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56349529/43615

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac App Store testing receipt validation (from receigen) "app is damaged and can't be opened."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600173/mac-app-store-testing-receipt-validation-from-receigen-app-is-damaged-and-can)

Comment: Yes, sure. But today I tried that again after updating to 10.15.4 and finally it seems that the issue was fixed by apple

Comment: @DaniilMolchanov 10.15.6 - the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to Catalina 10.15.4 it seems that the issue was already fixed by Apple.